# filtering out specific derivatives

Tags: python, function, math, tuples

I have generated several functions.

find_derivative simply takes the derivative of several terms using the product rule and makes a new equation.

So if i input  3x^2 + 2x^3

I get 6x + 6x^2

in the output [(6,1),(6,2)]

However I want to filter out any time I end up with an output with a tuple that begins with 0

```
def find_derivative(function_terms):
    new_function = []
    for term in function_terms:
        new_term = find_term_derivative(term)
        new_function.append(new_term)
        filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, new_function))
    return filtered_list
```

The expected result from input [(3, 2), (-11, 0)]
should be 
[(6, 1)]
but this code is not removing the second term, [0,-1]

EDIT: derivative function

```
def find_term_derivative(term): 
    x, y = term
    new_term = (x*y, y-1)
    return new_term
```

Comment: In fact, now i have tabbed in filtered list, my function removes any tuple which contains a 0, rather than one which only begins with a 0

Comment: Elimination of constant terms should be done either **by** `find_term_derivative` or **before** it.

Comment: How would i include filter here?

def find_term_derivative(term):
    x , y = term
    new_term = (x*y, y-1)
    return new_term

Comment: Don't [re-post earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666683/filtering-out-specific-terms). Be patient and wait for a response.

Comment: my new function still doesn't work.def find_term_derivative(term):
    x , y = term
    new_term = (x*y, y-1)
    filtered_term = list(filter(lambda x: x*y != 0, new_term))
    return filtered_term

It is still removing all signs of 0 instead of just x*y = 0

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with the filter, but take a look at the lambda you've written.  You're filtering on the condition `lambda x : x != 0`, which will check if the element in the list is not zero.

But the elements in your list are tuples, and you want to check if only the first number in the tuple is zero, so you need to update your condition to be `lambda x : x[0] != 0`.